# android: after click on button app crash

Tags: java, android

Hello I'm new to android app development and Java. I used some code from the internet and what Android studio generated. It needs to send a string over socket to a wifi shield to control a small boat with cargo. When I debug my app it starts, but when I click on any button it will crash. I tried to use logcat to find the problem but it don't show me anything.  I have used some error scope which I found here on stackoverflow and it is set on device. When I try seekBar the app doesn't crash and toast doesn't show after click.

After I run inspection on code I found this:

> 'public' method buttonConnectOnClickListener() is not exposed via an interface at line 69

It shows me the same problem on every button listener and I don't know how to fix it.

Here is Main.java:

```
    package tomasbenco.kop_android_controller;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
    import android.net.NetworkInfo;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.SeekBar;
    import android.widget.Switch;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.io.DataOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;

    public class Main extends Activity {
        private Button C1Button = null;
        private Button C2Button = null;
        private Switch lightsSwitch = null;
        private SeekBar RESB = null;
        private SeekBar LESB = null;
        private Boolean connected = Boolean.FALSE;
        private DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
        private Socket socket = null;
        private char[] transferReg = new char[7];

    private void setTransferReg(char transferReg, int i) {
        this.transferReg[i] = transferReg;
    }

    private char[] getTransferReg() {
        return transferReg;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        C1Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.C1Button);
        C2Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.C2Button);
        lightsSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.LightsSwitch);
        RESB = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.REseekBar);
        LESB = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.LEseekBar);
    }

    private void changeConnectionStatus(Boolean isConnected) {
        connected = isConnected;
        if (isConnected) {
            C1Button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            C2Button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            lightsSwitch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            RESB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            LESB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            C1Button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            C2Button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            lightsSwitch.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            RESB.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            LESB.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }


    public void buttonConnectOnClickListener(View view) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo wifiInfo = connectivity.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        if (wifiInfo.isConnected()) {
            if (!connected) {
                try {
                    socket = new Socket("192.168.137.1", 55555);
                    Toast msg = Toast.makeText(Main.this,
                            "Connected Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    msg.show();
                    dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    changeConnectionStatus(Boolean.TRUE);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    changeConnectionStatus(Boolean.FALSE);
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                    Toast msg = Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Disconnected Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    msg.show();
                    changeConnectionStatus(Boolean.FALSE);
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    changeConnectionStatus(Boolean.FALSE);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    changeConnectionStatus(Boolean.FALSE);
                }
            }
        } else {
            Toast msg = Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Wifi is not connected !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            msg.show();
        }
    }


    public void C1ButtonOnClickListener(View view) {
        if (C1Button.isActivated()) {
            Toast msg = Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Front cargo bay is opening !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            msg.show();
            transfer_REG(4, '1');
        } else {
            Toast msg = Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Front cargo bay is closing !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            msg.show();
            transfer_REG(4, '0');
        }
    }

    public void C2ButtonOnClickListener(View view) {
        if (C2Button.isActivated()) {
            Toast msg = Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Back cargo bay is opening !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            msg.show();
            transfer_REG(5, '1');
        } else {
            Toast msg = Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Back cargo bay is closing !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            msg.show();
            transfer_REG(5, '0');
        }
    }

    public void lightsButtonOnClickListener(View view) {
        if (C2Button.isActivated()) {
            Toast msg = Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Back cargo bay is opening !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            msg.show();
            transfer_REG(6, '1');
        } else {
            Toast msg = Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Back cargo bay is closing !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            msg.show();
            transfer_REG(6, '0');
        }
    }

    private void transfer_REG(int i, char trans) {
        setTransferReg(trans, i);
        String transfer = new String(getTransferReg());
        if (connected) try {
            dataOutputStream.writeChars(transfer);
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        }
    }

    public void REListener(View view) {
        if (RESB.getProgress() < 10) {
            transfer_REG(2, Integer.toString(RESB.getProgress()).charAt(0));
            transfer_REG(3, '1');
        } else {
            transfer_REG(2, Integer.toString(RESB.getProgress() - 10).charAt(0));
            transfer_REG(3, '0');
        }
    }

    public void LEListener(View view) {
        if (LESB.getProgress() < 10) {
            transfer_REG(1, Integer.toString(LESB.getProgress()).charAt(0));
            transfer_REG(2, '1');
            Toast msg = Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Left engine power is: -" + Integer.toString(LESB.getProgress()).charAt(0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            msg.show();
        } else {
            transfer_REG(1, Integer.toString(LESB.getProgress() - 10).charAt(0));
            transfer_REG(2, '0');
            Toast msg = Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Left engine power is: " + Integer.toString(LESB.getProgress() - 10).charAt(0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            msg.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is Main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
style="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Main">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/REtView"
    style="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/REseekBar"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:text="@string/RE"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ffaec0ff"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:theme="@style/Holo"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/LEtView"
    style="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/LEseekBar"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:text="@string/LE"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ffaec0ff"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:theme="@style/Holo"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/LEseekBar"
    style="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/LightsSwitch"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:max="20"
    android:onClick="LEListener"
    android:progress="10"
    android:theme="@style/Holo"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/REseekBar"
    style="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/REtView"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/LightsSwitch"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:max="20"
    android:onClick="REListener"
    android:progress="10"
    android:theme="@style/Holo"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/connButton"
    style="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="buttonConnectOnClickListener"
    android:text="@string/conn"
    android:textColor="#ffaec0ff"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:theme="@style/Holo"
    android:typeface="normal"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/C1Button"
    style="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="C1ButtonOnClickListener"
    android:text="@string/C1"
    android:textColor="#ffaec0ff"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:theme="@style/Holo"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/C2Button"
    style="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/C1Button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="C2ButtonOnClickListener"
    android:text="@string/C2"
    android:textColor="#ffaec0ff"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:theme="@style/Holo"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/LightsSwitch"
    style="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/C2Button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:checked="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="lightsButtonOnClickListener"
    android:showText="false"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/light"
    android:textColor="#ffaec0ff"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:theme="@style/Holo"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

Here is manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Post the stack trace

Comment: Please use the primitive version of `boolean`. Also, make sure you follow Java code style conventions.

Comment: I didn't find any listener's registration code in your snippet!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code,

Declare button globally like the rest of the two buttons;

```
private Button connButton;
```

put this code where you declare all your ids.

```
connButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you see in your android manifest whether you have this permission?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

I tried to copy your code and execute and this was the problem I was getting with the top button. Once this is added in Android manifest, then issue is resolved.

As you didn't post the AndroidManifest.xml, it is hard to say which permission you might have declared there. So can you check if this is there already, and if not, can you add this and try?

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for help but i had it there from begining and i added the manifest too

Comment: Can you paste your logcat error please? Your code worked with me somehow after some customization. Like I removed the style attribute to get it running. If you paste the stacktrace that will show the error properly.